# Two different implementation of module.provider() in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I currently understand the differences between service,factory and provider. However, I'm stuck at a point while understanding module.provider() function. There are lots of tutorials which explains the differences between service,factory,provider methods. I read many of them, however I didn't find any tutorial explainig module.provide() method in detail, didn't find any tutorial mentioning these two different approaches together.

I read from documents that provider is a configurable factory. Here is an example ( http://blog.xebia.com/differences-between-providers-in-angularjs/ ) :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.provider('movie', function () 
{
    var version;
    return {
        setVersion: function (value) {
            version = value;
        },
        $get: function () {
            return {
                title: 'The Matrix' + ' ' + version
            }
        }
    }
});
app.config(function (movieProvider) {
    movieProvider.setVersion('Reloaded');
});
```

After continuing researching about module.provider(), I find a different implementation. Here is the example ( http://tylermcginnis.com/angularjs-factory-vs-service-vs-provider/ ) :

[image]

I want to understand the logic behind these, not to memorize. In the first example, provider looks like a factory. It returns an object which includes a $get() method. I understand from this that provider function is invoked and it returns an object like factory when it is needed.

In the second one, it looks like a service because a property named thingFromConfig and $get() method is set using this keyword. I understand from this that provider function is invoked with new keyword and it returns an object like service when it is needed.

**Which one is correct? How can we understand these two different implementation of module.provide() ?**

**In the second case, what the this keyword inside provider() method and the this keyword inside this.$get() method refer to respectively?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's refer to the documentation for the `angular.module().provider` method which is, in fact, a [$provide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide) service's method:

> **provider(name, provider);**
>
> If the *provider* parameter is a constructor (function) - a new instance of the provider will be created using `$injector.instantiate()`, then treated as object.

So, the second parameter of the `provider` method is a constructor function used to create an instance of the provider (an object with `$get` method). Now, let's see the instantiation process, here the source of the `$injector.instantiate()` method:

```
function instantiate(Type, locals, serviceName) {
  var instance = Object.create((isArray(Type) ? Type[Type.length - 1] : Type).prototype || null);
  var returnedValue = invoke(Type, instance, locals, serviceName);

  return isObject(returnedValue) || isFunction(returnedValue) ? returnedValue : instance;
}
```

where `Type` is our provider constructor.

First, an `instance` object is created using the constructor's prototype. Then constructor (`Type`) is invoked with `this` bound to the newly created object `instance`. Now, notice the return statement:

- if the constructor returns an `object` (your first example) - it will be returned as a provider instance.
- if the constructor does not return anything (your second example) - the new object (`instance`, with your controller run against it) will be returned as a provider instance.

**Answers to your questions:**

- both ways are correct;
- the difference is how the provider is created: in the first case you explicitly return the provider instance from the constructor, in the second case it is created as a new `Object` and then the constructor function is run with `this` bound to this new `Object`;
- the `this` object in the provider constructor is what eventually will be used as a provider instance throughout the application (only if the constructor does NOT return an object explicitly);
- the `this` object in the `$get` function is the same thing - the provider instance's reference, when you inject your service somewhere for the first time the `$get` function will be invoked with `this` bound to the provider instance, whatever `$get` returns will be injected throughout your application as your service.

In addition to this, when you define your services using the `angular.module().service` shortcut method you can use both strategies as well, as internally the call to `service` method is similar to registering the following provider:

```
{
  $get: function() {
    return $injector.instantiate(constructor);
  }
}
```